# how to create url's as in google images

Tags: php, jquery, mod-rewrite

I am creating a website similar to google images. When an image is clicked (expanded) in google images the url changes to that particular image of google images. So when i copy and paste that url in a new browser window the same image shows up expanded. Any idea how this is done? And also how to shorten the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JavaScript

```
pushState()
```

Or

```
replaceState()
```

replaceState() will change the URL in the browser

pushState() will change the URL, and keep the old one in the browser history